# "The processing of Group Policy failed" while doing gpupdate

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, msi

I'm trying to install MSI package from a Windows Server 2008 as a GPO in a computer-wide scope. When I log in to a Windows 7 client workstation and run:

```
gpupdate /force
```

I get the following error message:

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \\serv
ername.local\SysVol\servername.local\Policies\{D2BF1758-B0FB-4967-AE1A-216D3
A423309}\gpt.ini from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy s
ettings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be trans
ient and could be caused by one or more of the following:
a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller
 has not replicated to the current domain controller).
c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.

To diagnose the failure, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H GPReport.html f
rom the command line to access information about Group Policy results.
```

If I then run `GPRESULT /H GPReport.html` I get this error:

*It says I can't post images... sorry.*

Which reads:

> Group Policy Infrastructure failed due to the error listed below.
>
> The network path was not found.
>
> Note: Due to the GP Core failure, none of the other Group Policy
>   components processed their policy. Consequently, status information
>   for the other components is not available.

It is very frustrating. Can someone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Can you browse to the UNC path? You may have one or more of multiple issues, including name resolution (DNS), File replication (DFS or FRS), permissions, etc.